# Attempt to index a nil value in premake.lua

Tags: c++, lua, premake

I have made a premake.lua file for mye C++ Game Engine. But when i run `premake5.exe vs2017` i get the error:
`Game Engine/premake5.lua:35: attempt to index a nil value`
if i go to line 35 where it complaines i see this:

```lua
34  filter "system:windows":
35      cppdialect "C++17"
36      staticruntime "On"
37      systemversion "latest"
```

i found out that if i comment out line 34 it seems to work but then proceedes to giving the same error on line 49:

```lua
49  filter "configurations:Debug": 
50      defines "BZ_DEBUG"
51      symbols "On"
```

if i at try to comment out all my filter fields. i get this error:
`Error: [string "return cfg-architecture"]:1: attempt to perform arithmetic on a table value (global 'cfg') in token: cfg-architecture`

i have tried multiple versions of premake and have tried to compile multiple with different vs versions. But i get the same result every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have extra `:` after your string in `filter`. so you try to call `"some_string":cppdialect("C++17")` and string doesn't have that method.

Your code should be

```lua
filter "system:windows"
    cppdialect "C++17"
    staticruntime "On"
    systemversion "latest"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! now i feel incredibly stupid. :/